# Logarithmic Derivative of the Riemann Zeta Function and its relation to zeros

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am trying to study the proof to the following theorem:
If $|t| \geq 7/8$ and $5/6 \leq \sigma \leq 2$, then
$$ \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) = \sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{s-\rho} + O({\log \tau})$$
where $\tau = |t| + 4$ and the sum is extended over all zeros $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$ for which
$|\rho - (3/2 + it)| \leq 5/6$

Using the lemma:
Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain containing the disc
$|z| \leq 1$, that $|f(z)| \leq M$ in this disc, and that $f(0) \neq 0$. Let $r$ and $R$ be fixed,
$0 < r < R < 1$. Then for $|z| \leq r$ we have
$$ \frac{f'}{f}(z) = \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{1}{z-z_k}+ O({\log\frac{M}{|f(0)|}})    $$
where the sum is extended over all zeros $z_k$ of f for which $|z_k| \leq R$.

And

Let $\delta > 0$ be fixed. Then
$ \zeta (s) =
 \frac{1}{s - 1}
 + O(1)$
uniformly for s in the rectangle $\delta \leq \sigma \leq 2$, $|t| \leq 1$, and
$\zeta (s) \ll (1 + \tau^{1-\sigma} ) \min\{|\sigma - 1|,\log \tau\}$
,
uniformly for $\delta \leq \sigma \leq 2, |t| \geq 1.$

And the the proof of the theorem given in the book is:
We apply lemma 1 to the function $f (z) = \zeta (z + (3/2 + it))$, with
$R = 5/6$ and $r = 2/3$. To complete the proof it suffices to note that $| f (0)|\gg 1$ by the (absolutely convergent) Euler product formula, and that $f (z) \ll \tau$
for $|z| \leq 1$ by Corollary lemma 2

My question is that when does the author use the assumption $|t|\geq 7/8$ or where is it implied?

The book I am referring is MULTIPLICATIVE NUMBER THEORY I:CLASSICAL THEORY by HUGH L. MONTGOMERY and ROBERT C. VAUGHAN

Edit: Thank you @Gary for pointing out the error of me mentioning the wrong authors of the book
Edit: The theorem can be found in chapter 6 lemma 6.4 pg no.171. of the book mentioned above

Comment: That book is by Hugh L. Montgomery and Robert C. Vaughan.

Comment: Sorry I will edit the question

Comment: Could you please give a specific reference to the theorem number in the book?

Comment: @StevenClark It is lemma 6.4 and page no. 171, I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Somehow Montgomery & Vaughan's book always puts these strange fractions in the assumption, but all you need in this question is that $t$ cannot be too close to zero when $\sigma$ is near one (as it is a pole of $\zeta(s)$).

Comment: Thats what I had figured because for some arbitrary reason he chose 7/8 which doesn't even help with the numbers later on

Comment: @TravorLZH reading further into the proof of the prime number theorem I can see for some reason the author didn't incorporate $x$ on pg 180 when calculating asymptotic for $\sum_{x<n<3x/2} \Lambda (n) \min(1,\frac{x}{T|x-n|}) +\frac{(4x)^{\sigma_0}}{T} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda (n)}{n^{\sigma_0}}$, can you please verify or am I missing something?

Comment: @PrathamLalwani I wonder if this is relevant to the question. Perhaps it's better to open up a new question to discuss this.